# How to fix django admin foreign key display that used raw_id_fields

Tags: django, django-admin, django-1.8

I have recently migrated a website from Django 1.6 to Django 1.8 and I can't figure out the simple way to fix the behaviour of django admin when it displays foreignkey fields that use the "raw_id_fields" in the adminClass.

The use case is exactly the one from django book : http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter06.html (Figure 6-14)

```
class BookAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
    raw_id_fields = ('publisher',)
```

Administration display used to have a spyglass at the end allowing to pick a new foreignkey id, but now none is displayed.

Documentation hint's at some new mechanism but it's unclear how to apply it here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_overrides

Thanks

Comment: There's no new mechanism for applying raw_id_fields, and nothing has changed in that area since long before 1.4. I have a project running on 1.9 which shows the magnifying glass and link, with no other configuration. Maybe you should show the rest of the BookAdmin class?

Comment: Thanks, then maybe something I was doing before in the wrong way, that was changed. The only thing I can see is that i had the magnifying glass, and now it's gone. If i remove the raw_id_fields I go back to the standard display and if i set it i have the field with the id but not magnifying glass... Any idea what other place I could look into?

Comment: As I said, can you post the whole BookAdmin definition?

Comment: Thanks Daniel, the mistake was mine...

Answer (score 0):

As often, the problem was elsewhere, the statics from the admin had not been updated and i was using an older version of admin static files.

a simple `python manage.py collectatic` command fixed this issue.

For future reference, any issue with admin should start by making sure statics are up to date.